# What is the word for theatre that takes multiple nights to perform the entire story?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

Some plays are typically performed  in installments over multiple nights for the same audience, because a single night is not adequate for the entire story to be told. What is the theatre terminology that describes this—either a word for these type of plays, or the process of performing them over multiple nights? I’m not sure of the part or parts of speech of this word.

Examples:

> They will be performing Wagner’s *Ring* cycle as [word]—during the evening from Thursday to Sunday—because who has the patience to watch fifteen hours of opera in one sitting?

> I wouldn’t watch Tony Kushner’s *Angels in America* in [word]; I would rather watch both parts in the same night.

Comment: Is that a [serial](https://www.lexico.com/definition/serial)?

Comment: @WeatherVane, Almost, but I was looking for the word that could be applied to live, in-person performances, and “serial” is used only for plays in other media.

Comment: @ElizaWilson However it is (and was before broadcast media existed) used for printed stories presented over a number of editions of a magazine or newspaper. In fact I would suggest that the broadcast _serial_ derives its concept and description from print media. Just because 19th century theatre didn't (to my knowledge) adopt the serial performance there's no reason not to call a new type of stage performance _serial_. Whether you'd sell tickets for it or not is another matter.

Comment: @Bolden, that’s fair, but I do believe there is a word that has a history of usage in life theatre.

Comment: @ElizaWilson - why are you sure that a specific term exist apart from theatre?

Comment: @user66974 I believe I have heard and read this term several times before, but I am not completely sure.

Comment: Both of these use the word *parts*. [*The four parts that constitute the Ring cycle are...*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Ring_des_Nibelungen) and [*Angels in America: A Gay Fantasia on National Themes is a two-part play...*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angels_in_America)

Comment: Self-indulgence?

Comment: a _filibuster_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In an academic article about supposed multi-day performances of a particular work at a particular place, Lucy Monro used the expressions, "multi-day play" or "multi-day performance" of a play.  In skimming through the article, I did not see any other term expressing the same idea.  The article is available on JSTOR and cites a few other articles about similar performances.  It's at least a place to start.

Munro, Lucy. “Governing the Pen to the Capacity of the Stage: Reading the Red Bull and Clerkenwell.” Early Theatre, vol. 9, no. 2, 2006, pp. 99–113. JSTOR, [www.jstor.org/stable/43500657](https://www.jstor.org/stable/43500657). Accessed 22 Feb. 2021.

Comment: I'm not sure now whether there is any such word that I was thinking of, but this seems close enough.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the word you're looking for is "episodic".  For example from [Performing Hybridity in Colonial-Modern China](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Performing_Hybridity_in_Colonial_Modern/99Vh1uKMfhgC?hl=en&gbpv=0):

> The play's episodic structure also borrowed from the Shanghai jingju practice of episodic installment plays (*liantai benxi*) that was popular with new plays of the time. Running over multiple nights, each installment would end with cliffhangers...